# Three.js, unexpected position shift when scaling object

Tags: three.js, position, scale

I'm trying to create a zoom box, so far I managed to translate the cursor positions from locale to world coordinates and create a box object around the cursor with the right uvs.

Here is the fiddle of my attempt :  https://jsfiddle.net/2ynfedvk/2/

Without scaling the box is perfectly centered around the cursor, but if you toggle the scaling checkbox to set the scale `zoomMesh.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1)`, the box position shift the further you move the cursor from the scene center.

Am I messing any CSS like "transform origin" for three.js to center the scale around the object, is this the right approach the get this kind of zoom effect ?

I'm new to three.js and 3d in general, so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you scale your mesh with 1.5, it means that apply transform matrix that scales values of vertices.

The issue comes from changing of vertices. Vertices are in local space of the mesh. And when you set the left-top vertex of the square, for example, to `[10, 10, 0]` and then apply `.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1)` to the mesh, then the coordinate of vertex became `[15, 15, 0]`. The same to all the other 3 vertices. And that's why the center of the square does not match at 1.5 times from the center of the picture to mouse pointer.

So, an option is not to scale a mesh, but change the size of the square.

I changed your fiddle a bit, so maybe it will be more explanatory:

```js
const
  [width, height] = [500, 300],
  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
  scaleCheckBox = document.querySelector('input')
;

console.log(scaleCheckBox)

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

const
  scene = new THREE.Scene(),
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas}),
  camDistance = 5,
  camFov = (2 * Math.atan( height / ( 2 * camDistance ) ) * ( 180 / Math.PI )),
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(camFov, width/height, 0.1, 1000 )
;

camera.position.z = camDistance;

const
  texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://picsum.photos/500/300" ),
  imageMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture , side : 0 } )
;

texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

const
  planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width, height ),
  planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, imageMaterial )
;

const
  zoomGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
  zoomMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture , side : 0 } ),
  zoomMesh = new THREE.Mesh( zoomGeometry, zoomMaterial )
;

zoomMaterial.color.set(0xff0000);

zoomGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
  0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0
]), 3));

zoomGeometry.setIndex([
  0, 1, 2,
  2, 1, 3
]);

scene.add( planeMesh );
scene.add( zoomMesh );

var zoom = 1.;

function setZoomBox(e){

  const
    size = 50 * zoom, 
    x = e.clientX - (size/2),
    y = -(e.clientY - height) - (size/2),
    coords = [
      x,
      y,
      x + size,
      y + size
    ]
  ;
  
  const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = [
    coords[0] - (width/2),
    coords[1] - (height/2),
    coords[2] - (width/2),
    coords[3] - (height/2)
  ];
  
  zoomGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
    x1, y1, 0,
    x2, y1, 0,
    x1, y2, 0,
    x2, y2, 0
  ]), 3));
  
  const [u1, v1, u2, v2] = [
    coords[0]/width,
    coords[1]/height,
    coords[2]/width,
    coords[3]/height
  ]
  
  zoomGeometry.setAttribute('uv',
  new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
    u1, v1,
    u2, v1,
    u1, v2,
  
    u2, v2,
    u1, v1,
    u1, v2
  ]), 2));

}

function setScale(e){
  //zoomMesh.scale.set(...(scaleCheckBox.checked ? [1.5, 1.5, 1] : [1, 1, 1]));
  zoom = scaleCheckBox.checked ? 1.5 : 1 ;
  
}

function render(){

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', setZoomBox);
scaleCheckBox.addEventListener('change', setScale);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    font: bold 16px arial;
}

canvas{
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

<canvas></canvas>
<div>Toggle scale <input type="checkbox" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, not quite what I was looking for (not only resize the square but also zoom in the image), but you pointed me in the right direction.

Like you said the positions coordinate are shifting with the scale, so I have to recalculate the new position relative to the scale.

Added these new lines, with new `scale` and `offset` variables :

```
if(scaleCheckBox.checked){
    const offset = scale - 1;
    zoomMesh.position.set(
        -(x1 * offset) - (size*scale)/2) -(size/2),
        -((y1 * offset) + (size*scale)/2) -(size/2)),
        0
    );
}
```

Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dc9f5v0m/

It's a bit messy, with a lot of recalculation (Especially to center the cursor around the square), but it gets the job done and the zoom effect can be achieved with any shape not only a square.

Thanks again for your help.